# android - EditText lagging

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-edittext

I've an array of edittext(12), inizialized in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < solution.length(); i++) {
            int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(idName + i, "id",
                    context.getPackageName());
            editText[i] = (EditText) layout.findViewById(resID);
            editText[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editText[i].setEnabled(true);
            editText[i]
                    .setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.AllCaps(),
                            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1) }); 

}
```

my xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutsolutionhorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal0"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal1"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal2"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal3"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal4"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal5"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal6"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal7"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal8"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal9"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal10"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonclearhorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtsolutionhorizontal11"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/clearbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

for every edittext there a listenrer:

```
for (int j = 0; j < editTextVertical.length; j++) {
                    editTextVertical[j]
                            .addTextChangedListener(new EditTextInputTextWatcherListener(
                                    editTextVertical, editTextVertical[j], j));
                }
```

where EditTextInputTextWatcherListener is:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // System.out.println(s.charAt(count-1) + " character to send");
        if (editText1.getText().toString().length() == 1
                && !editText1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            if (index < 11)
                editText[index + 1].requestFocus();
        } else if (editText1.getText().toString().length() == 0
                && editText1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            editText[index].requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

if the edittext is 3 or 5 is ok, but when the edittext are greater I've a lot of lag when I input text.
If I wrote a letter in a edittext, I see this letter after 1s.

I've this problem with emulator and device.
Is possible to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Provide more description, what do you meant by lag..?

Comment: @Pragnani :D recently i clicked on your profil and you had 353 answers. After two days when you posted a lot of answers you had 353 answers again, today i clicked and you have 347 answers. black magic? :))

Comment: @Pragnani i know that :) i only mentioned that(there is no PM). black magic was only for fun.

Comment: @Pragnani i knew that but i was not sure so i only ask and i thought that if i write black magic, it makes you smile and thanks.

Comment: @Sajmon May be we can delete these comments below this question, because they are not subjected about this question.

Comment: resolved con inputtype visiblepassword